# Re-loading remote drools guvnor resource at drools-camel-server

Tags: drools, reloading

I am using drools-camel-server 5.4 final to execute the rules fetched from guvnor on jboss AS7 as follows:

```
    <drools:resource type="PKG" source="http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/mypackage/Test"
                            basic-authentication="enabled" username="test" password="test" />
    </drools:resources>
    <drools:ksession id="ksession1" type="stateless" 
            kbase="kbase" node="node1" />
```

how can I reload or rebuild the knowledgebase so that any changes in the rules instantly get reflected on execution server?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can by adding a knowledge agent and a resource change scanner... here is my working example

```
<drools:resource-change-scanner id="s1" interval="10" enabled="true"/>
<drools:kagent kbase="kbase1" id="kagent" new-instance="false"/> 

<drools:grid-node id="node1"/>

<drools:ksession id="ksession1" type="stateless" kbase="kbase1" node="node1"/>

<drools:kbase id="kbase1" node="node1">
   <drools:resources>
      <drools:resource  type="DRL" source="classpath:test.drl"/>
   </drools:resources>
</drools:kbase>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I believe this is the correct way, however I am unable to make it work when source is remote. may be I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Could not find any solution anywhere.  I had resulted to trial and error and eventually for what seems to work for me.  It detects when my remote resources in Guvnor has been updated.

```
<drools:resource-change-scanner id="s1" interval="10" enabled="true" />
<drools:resource id="cs" type="CHANGE_SET" source="http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor/rest/packages/com.test/assets/CHANGE_SET/source" basic-authentication="enabled" username="admin" password="admin" />

<drools:kagent kbase="kbase1" id="kagent" new-instance="false">
    <drools:resources>
        <drools:resource ref="cs" />
    </drools:resources>
</drools:kagent>

<drools:grid-node id="node1"/> 
<drools:ksession id="ksession1" type="stateless" kbase="kbase1" node="node1"/>

<drools:kbase id="kbase1" node="node1">
    <drools:resources>
        <drools:resource ref="cs" />
    </drools:resources>
</drools:kbase>
```