# Editing Drools within a Web Service using Guvnor

Tags: web-services, jax-rs, drools

We have just started work on with Drools exposed as a RESTful web service (starting with the example in the Drools Integration download available at http://www.jboss.org/drools/downloads.html, our project looks similar to this http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.CR1/droolsjbpm-integration-docs/html/ch03.html#). This results in a .wadl which looks like this:

```
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <grammars/>
    <resources base="http://localhost:8080/msci-poc-drools-server/kservice/rest">
        <resource path="/">
            <resource path="execute">
                <method name="POST">
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>
```

What we would like to do is allow editing of the rules in Drools via the Guvnor application. I'm not sure whether this is possible (Guvnor seems to wrap it's own instance of a Drools knowledge base as far I can tell) although. Is this possible? How easy is it to do?

**I suppose my question is really this, how do I have a Drools which is exposed as a web service which I can also edit using Guvnor if I want to?**

Comment: I think you refer to something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852984/re-loading-remote-drools-guvnor-resource-at-drools-camel-server

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to embed the rule editor functionality of Guvnor into your web application.

See http://www.plugtree.com/guvnor-embed-asset%E2%80%99s-editor-in-your-application/